# How do CH-47 pilots lower the tail during a pinnacle landing?

Tags: helicopter, pilot-technique, ch-47

[image]
([thedrive.com](http://www.thedrive.com/the-war-zone/22167/watch-this-ch-47-chinook-stick-an-awesome-pinnacle-landing-during-mount-hood-rescue))

Given the recent [rescue of a climber on Mt. Hood](http://www.thedrive.com/the-war-zone/22167/watch-this-ch-47-chinook-stick-an-awesome-pinnacle-landing-during-mount-hood-rescue) by a Chinook, how are the pilots able to lower the tail in this situation? Is this just the natural angle during a hover, or are there some adjustments the pilots can make to the fore and aft collective individually?

Comment: Related: [Why would a helicopter hold a 'nose-up' in hover?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/33486/1696)

Comment: [Related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/26826/62)

Comment: I wonder what would the angle inside looks like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A careful balance of nose-up cyclic and decreased collective to stick the aft of the ship firmly in place. Not so much a landing, as flying with the aft gear and ramp planted.

Answer (score 1):

Because the helo is barely hovering in level flight with the aft landing gear resting on the inclined snow pack.  It doesn’t lower its tail as such.